# Рекурсивный импорт в Python

Tags: python, рекурсия

Просьба подробно объяснить мне глупому поведение циклического импорта из книги

Марка Лутца # Изучаем Python [4-ое издание]:

Часть 5. Модули >> Упражнение 7. Циклический импорт:

***# recur1.py***

```
X = 1

import recur2

Y = 2
```

***# recur2.py***

```
from recur1 import X

from recur1 import Y
```

В зависимости от порядка импорта каждого файла и прямого их запуска в интерактивной оболочке. Итого = 4 ситуации.

Всю голову себе изломал, но никак не въеду.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

**recur1.py**:

```
print('x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file')
x = 1

print('import recur2... We are in recur1 file')
import recur2

print('y = 2, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file')
y = 2
```

**recur2.py**:

```
print('import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file')
from recur1 import x

print('import y from recur1... We are in recur2 file')
from recur1 import y

print('hi from recur2! We are in recur2 file')
```

В ходе импортирования инструкции в файле выполняются сначала и до конца.

Если выполним следующее:

```
>>> import recur1
```

То получим ошибку:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'y'
```

Это происходит по очень простой причине. В модуле **recur1** сначала создается переменная **x**, а потом сразу импортируется **recur2**, в котором мы используем **from**.

Таким образом, у нас будет доступ только к тем именам, которые уже были определены в этом модуле. То есть доступ только к **x**, **y** не будет доступен, так как к нему будет присвоено значение после импорта в **recur1**.

```
from recur1 import y # а у еще нет!
```

Лучше не использовать при рекурсивном импорте инструкцию **from**. При рекурсивном импорте интерпретатор не будет повторно выполнять инструкции.

Это легко можно проверить:

```
>>> import recur2
import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file
x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import recur2... We are in recur1 file
y = 2, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import y from recur1... We are in recur2 file
hi from recur2! We are in recur2 file
```

Ошибки не происходит, потому что при первом импорте мы получаем **x**, потом снова импортируем из **recur1** **recur2**, повторного определения переменной **х** происходить не будет (см. выше), поэтому сразу получим **y**, и когда уже захотим импортнуть его из **recur2**, также повторно инструкции не будут выполняться.

Идем дальше:

```
>>> from sys import modules
>>> 'recur1' in modules.keys()
False
>>> 'recur2' in modules.keys()
False
>>> import recur2
# вывод см. выше
>>> 'recur2' in modules.keys()
True
>>> 'recur1' in modules.keys()
True
```

И когда после этого мы захотим сразу сделать:

```
>>> import recur1
```

То ошибки в

```
from recur1 import y
```

не будет, так как y уже будет объявлен в **recur1**:

```
>>> help(modules['recur1'])
```

Вернет:

```
NAME
    recur1

DATA
    x = 1
    y = 2
```

Если же запустим

```
python recur1.py
```

Получим:

```
x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import recur2... We are in recur1 file
import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file
x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import recur2... We are in recur1 file
y = 2, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import y from recur1... We are in recur2 file
hi from recur2! We are in recur2 file
y = 2, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
```

Как пишет Лутц:

> Когда модули запускаются как самостоятельные программы, они не
>   импортируются, поэтому здесь возникает тот же эффект, как и при
>   импортировании recur2 в интерактивной оболочке, – recur2 является
>   первым импортируемым модулем.

А при

```
python recur2.py
```

В выводе увидим:

```
import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file
x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import recur2... We are in recur1 file
import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file
import y from recur1... We are in recur2 file
ImportError: cannot import name 'y'
```

То есть мы еще не объявили в **recur1** переменную **y**, поэтому ее и нет.

Если допустил какие-то неточности, заранее прошу прощения. Ответ получился большим, мог и упустить что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Я аналогично предварительно экспериментировал с трассировкой, но объяснения Лутцом рекурсивного импорта порядком меня запутали. А потом всё встало на свои места:

1. Создание объекта модуля инструкцией **import** происходит лишь единожды, далее - интерпретатор пропускает все последующие вызовы **import** этого модуля и занимается выполнением иных инструкций с дополнением пространства имён.
2. Инструкция **from** является расширенной версией инструкции **import** с дополнительной операцией копирования имён *импортируемого модуля* в пространство имён *импортирующего модуля*.

Кстати, решение Лутца

> Решение? Не используйте инструкцию from в операции рекурсивного
>   импорта (в самом деле!). Интерпретатор не зациклится, если вы все-таки
>   сделаете это, но ваша программа попадет в зависимость от порядка
>   следования инструкций в модулях.

...

> Если от циклов не удается избавиться полностью, попробуйте отсрочить
>   обращение к именам модуля, используя инструкции import и полные имена
>   (вместо инструкции from),

**recur1.py**

```
print('x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file')
x = 1

print('import recur2... We are in recur1 file')
import recur2

print('y = 2, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file')
y = 2
```

**recur2.py**

```
print('import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file')
import recur1 # Вместо from recur1 import x, y

print('x =', recur1.x)
print('y =', recur1.y)
```

не актуально:

```
>>> import recur1
x = 1, hi from recur1! We are in recur1 file
import recur2... We are in recur1 file
import x from recur1... We are in recur2 file
x = 1
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Отблагодарить репутация на сайте не позволяет.

(*Голос за requires 15 reputation.*)